# Outgoing connections from dedicated server denied with iptables shut off

Tags: wordpress, http, iptables, dedicated-server

I have a peculiar problem with my dedicated webserver. It's running CentOS and uses PLESK for administration through web.

I noticed the problem in the title when trying to update plugins in wordpress aswell as wordpress itself. When trying to update a plugin or wordpress it throws me this error:

"Download failed.: Failed to connect to 72.233.56.139: Permission denied"

First thing I did was to apply a rule (in the PLESK firewall) that allowed both incoming and outgoing traffic to the IP, but to no avail. I further investigated this by SSHing into the server and checking the iptables, which has the following outgoing rules:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02     reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            72.233.56.138
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            72.233.56.138
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            72.233.69.88
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            72.233.69.89
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            66.135.58.62
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            66.135.58.61
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            72.233.69.88
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            72.233.69.89
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            66.135.58.62
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            66.135.58.61
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The other IPs are for the Akismet anti-spam filter which is also not working (it cannot connect to the akismet servers).

I contacted my host and they looked into it, but the reply I got was that they didn't know (!) what caused the problem and said I needed to figure it out myself.

First thing I tried was to stop iptables and opening up everything, but I still get permission denied on outgoing traffic (incoming is allowed and works perfectly as people can comment/spam like crazy on my blog).

Does anyone know what I could try to further troubleshoot this? It seems very strange that the traffic is still blocked even though the firewall is completely (?) shut down using "iptables stop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all things, I eventually found out that the problem was caused by selinux which was set to "enforced". I changed it using

```
# nano -w etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

And changing the line "SELINUX=enforcing" to "SELINUX=permissive" and reboot my server. Now everything is working as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

take this stop firewall script; it works.

```
#! /bin/bash

# In order to flush all iptables rules , Run the following commands :

/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables -X
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F
/sbin/iptables -t nat -X
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -F
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -X
/sbin/iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: After running the first command, the connection timed out and now I can't access the server at all...

Comment: ///-F, --flush [chain]
Flush the selected chain (all the chains in the table if none is given). This is equivalent to deleting all the rules one by one.///

Off course if you run that command from an SSH session that somehow requires netfilter services to reach the server and you flushed iptables rules you will not be able to continue with the session... You asked how to really stop an iptables firewal; you got it.

Comment: Plus I gave you a script; you should've run it as a script and no as individual commands. running the whole script ensures you there are no netfilter restrictions and you should've been able to restart any broken session rigth away.

Comment: Thats ok, called support and they just stopped the service. But even though the service is stopped, my server still wont allow outgoing connections.

And (sorry for being a noob her) how exactly would I proceed to run this as a script? I'm just a developer and use windows for daily use so linux is just as good as greek to me.

Comment: not a problem I understand; you have to create the script file with the content I gave you then you have to make it executable with #chmod +x myscriptname  then run #./myscriptname

Comment: Took a crash course on google and ran the script, but to no avail. Wordpress still wont allow me to make outgoing connections.

The funny thing is that I can ping the wordpress IP (72.233.56.138) from SSH, but my wordpress still sais permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and your solution did work. However, the solution I found here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/how-do-i-configure-selinux-to-allow-outbound-connections-from-a-cgi-script
was able to fix it as well without the need of completely disabling the SELinux firewall features.